# Google plus integration

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

When i going to make intent with form(this) a error occurred.

```
Intent shareIntent = PlusShare.Builder
                    .form(this)
                    .setText(
                            "Check out: http://example.com/cheesecake/lemon")
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setContent(
                            Uri.parse("http://example.com/cheesecake/lemon"))
                    .getIntent();
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

can any one please help me?

Comment: **What does the error _say_?** Did you read it?

Comment: thanks for reply, .form(this) is making error sign.and error is "The method form(MainActivity) is undefined for the type PlusShare.Builder"

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the `form()` method from? Can't find it anywhere in the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusShare.Builder.html

try this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                .setText(
                        "Check out: http://example.com/cheesecake/lemon")
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setContent(
                        Uri.parse("http://example.com/cheesecake/lemon"))
                .getIntent();
        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: In that case setContent(Uri) is undefines for the type PlusShare.Bulder.